# error:disallowed_useragent in google login using socialauth android

Tags: android, socialauth

i am using SocialAuth for login Facebook and google

it was working and Facebook is also working.

but google is stopped from just few days

it show me error

403. That’s an error.

Error: disallowed_useragent

This user-agent is not permitted to make an OAuth authorization request to Google as it is classified as an embedded user-agent (also known as a web-view). Per our policy, only browsers are permitted to make authorization requests to Google. We offer several libraries and samples for native apps to perform authorization requests in the browser.

Learn more

Request Details
That’s all we know

[image: Bellow is image]

Comment: which Auth you are using?

Comment: SocialAuth 3.2 latest library

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you didn't give enough information about your building tool and platform.
I've once faced this issue with React Native Webview, all I did was to add **userAgent** and everything worked smoothly... I learnt Google changed their policies thereby stopping webview from using their social login, The userAgent makes google sees your request to be coming from normal web browser.
If you're on another platform than React Native, just look for a way to add or change your userAgent to what i have below

```
<WebView
        source={{uri: 'my_website_url'}} 
        userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
      />
```